# FFMpegCore .Net library stream video over udp

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

I attempt to stream a video I got as file using FFMpegCore over network using UDP without any modifications to the original video.

Maybe there is a easier solution to this problem without using FFmpeg, but in future I also need to receive a stream and decode it using FFmpeg so the best approach is to maybe just use the library for this task.

I don't really know where to start with, I'm thankful for any tip.

Comment: _"without any modifications to the original video"_ - you can stream the data then but in order to make it a streaming _video_ you _need_ to change some of it.

Comment: _"I don't really know where to start with, I'm thankful for any tip."_ - Ok, here you go: First, read up on and understand the difference between static video formats and _streaming_ video formats, and how you transpose one into the other. Probably won't hurt to get into protocols like RTP/RTSP(/RTCP), too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll lookup the given topics, maybe this clears things up for me.